# How to change places of two numbers in an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, function

I am creating an bubble sorting program in C using `for`, and I am trying to when a number be more high than another in this array, they are going to change places.

Example :

The user enters with the input :

```
Input : 5,6,10,9,2
```

The output will be the highest number in first place and the others in one sequence, like that :

```
Output : 10,9,6,5,2
```

**My code :**

```
int array[5],i,changed = false;

for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if(array[i] > array[i+1]) {
        swap(array[i],array[i+1]); //Function that exchanges place, but I don't know how to do that
        changed = true;
    }
}
```

How can I do that works ?

Comment: Okay, I will look the question, if didn't work, I will change my question.

Comment: BTW `array[i+1]` might occurs out-of-bounds.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I search for duplicate before answer, I only find similar but not duplicate, your question is indeed a duplicate but hard to understand because your duplicate should be close as simple typo error.

Comment: like [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RoL6kmu7MWQjk3Xv)

Comment: Thank you BLUEPIXY, you too helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argument function in C are all pass by copy, so you need to use pointer:

```
void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int save_a = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = save_a;
}
```

Then you could use this function like this:

```
swap(&array[i], &array[i + 1]);
```

or:

```
swap(array + i, array + i + 1);
```

Comment: He does wrong the swap, because the values don't match the numbers from the input. He shows just one value and the others as 0, how can I correct that ?

Comment: @Monteiro What ? Your question is about swap two value. My answer give you a way to swap them. Like BLUEPIXY said your code is undefined behavior because you have an out of bounds index. Your bubble sort is broken but this is not the purpose of your question. I invite you to search about how to code a bubble sort.

Comment: You are right @Stargateur, going to give you +1 and answer correct, sorry for saying that, anyway, thanks for the help.